# Multiple nodelets?

Tags: ros, multi-thread, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to create an application that subscribes to messages from topic A and publishes to topic B based on the message received from A. While waiting for messages from A, it should publish default messages on B in the meantime. So in short, the publishing action to B should work independent of whether messages are received on A or not..

Is using the nodelets a good idea for this application? If so, how do I make two nodelets that share the same variables so that B process the variables received from A?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44402/multiple-nodelets?/) by [devmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/3245/devmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless you need to transfer a lot of data from one node to another there is basically no need to use nodelets.

The process you described is naturally organized by callback function specified as a parameter to `subscribe` method. By means of state variable in that callback you can modify published data in the main loop.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2